# How do I make an equivalent dynamic transact sql block?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I have a problem about T-SQL Dynamic SP. The first block is my failure attempt, and the second is my target (non-dynamic block).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UDP1_TRY_EQQQ
(@FACTUTABLE nvarchar(100))
AS 
declare @sqlquery as nvarchar(100)
BEGIN
SET @sqlquery = 'DELETE FROM ' + @FACTUTABLE + ' WHERE ANEXO IN 
    (SELECT ANEXO FROM ' + @FACTUTABLE + ' A LEFT JOIN ALTAS_MOVILES B 
    ON A.ANEXO=B.TCNFOL WHERE B.TCNFOL IS NULL)'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @sqlquery
END


DELETE FROM FACTURACION_201210
WHERE ANEXO IN 
(
SELECT ANEXO
FROM FACTURACION_201210 A
LEFT JOIN ALTAS_MOVILES B
ON A.ANEXO=B.TCNFOL
WHERE B.TCNFOL IS NULL
)
```

Comment: What does "failure attempt" mean? Do you get an error message, delete the wrong rows, etc.? Please be specific when framing questions here. It's much harder to fix "it's not working" than it is to troubleshoot something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only allowed 100 characters for your @sqlquery variable. Make it bigger.

Also, in these dynamic queries where you need to substitute a table name, I like to take two additional precautions:

1. Use [QUOTENAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). For example: `@sql = 'Select * FROM ' + QuoteName(@table);`
2. Look up the table name in the information_schema, to make sure it's not gonna cause a syntax error: `SELECT Table_Name FROM Information_schema.Tables WHERE Table_Name = @FACTUTABLE;`

If you want to get real fancy, you can also check that the table is in the right schema and even check within information_schema.columns to make sure the chosen table has the right column names, but normally just these first two checks is as far as I go.

Comment: Good eye Joel, +1. Though I will suggest that using `QUOTENAME()` is far safer than explicitly adding square brackets.